# Firebase java client

Tags: java, firebase

I had a look at firebase java client for Android. I see that it also provides a java client. Is it fair to assume that they use the same API then.

Is the only thing that differentiates them the setContext?

What is the reason for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android-specific client library includes additional features and functionality particular to mobile development, such as (beta) offline support / disk persistence and automatic auth. session management.

Comment: Ok cool. But this library works out of the box for Java aswell? No need to register anything global?

Comment: @vonGohren You'll want to use the appropriate client for the appropriate platform. The pure JVM client has to global registration method required.

Comment: Where is the pure JVM client? The only place i can find it is here in the changelog: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/changelog.html. There they have a JVM link. But they where is the library?

Comment: Search for "plain Java" on [https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html).

Comment: Are there any api reference for the plain java or is it the same as android?

Comment: It's the same as Android, with the exception of the `setContext()` method